# adding content type programmatically null reference exception

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, development, sharepoint-server

I'm trying to add programmatically a Content Type to a SPList. Howerver i got a null reference exception.

I followed the MSDN to do it : [enter link description here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa543576(v=office.14).aspx/%22msdn%20link%22)

```
SPContentType test = web.AvailableContentTypes["test"];
newList.ContentTypes.Add(test);
newList.Update();
```

I tried to add several boolean like :

```
web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
newList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
```

But the problem is still the same my newList.ContentTypes.Add(test) didn't work.
Btw my Content Type test isn't null, and newlist is the good one.

Any ideas ?

Comment: can you check in site actions > content types , if this "test" content type is available or not, or you may check AvailableContentTypes via debugging for its property

Comment: is by chance "newList.ContentTypes" null while you debug?

Comment: My content type is available, and the crazy thing is that i can add it through IHM it works perfectly,  but it don't work with my code.

Comment: I found the solution ! I have created a new content type and with this below code it works perfectly. So i understood that the problem came from my content type. The problem was i changed several column site but i didn't delete and add it again on my content type...thanks all for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

After you're being sure `test` actually exists and is not `null` itself, try in that order:

```
SPContentType test = web.AvailableContentTypes["test"];
newList.ContentTypesEnabled = true;
newList.Update();
newList.ContentTypes.Add(test);
```

First note that we need to update the list after setting `ContentTypesEnabled` to `true` (`ContentTypesEnabled` must be `true` so we can add content types on the list).
Also note that the final `Update` is not required since, most of the time, add operations are immediate.

And, as a side note, `web.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true` won't be needed neither in the following cases:

- if you're in a Console app, a Timer Job, a Windows app (i.e. not in a Web context);
- or if you use the contextual `SPWeb` (the one from `SPContext.Current.Web`) *and* you're in a POSTback HTTP request.

Comment: thanks for you answer, unfortunately i still get the same error. Thanks for the precision about AllowUnsafeUpdates